# How to remove unnecessary options from Salesforce Community Chatter page

Tags: community, chatter

I am getting Workbench option in my Community Chatter page.
Please suggest how I can remove 'Workbench' option from my Chatter UI page (/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage).

[image: Sanp shot of Chatter UI]

Answer (score 1):

Workbench is a Canvas App in your instance. You can select where canvas apps appears in the settings for your app:

1. In the Salesforce application, from Setup, click Create | Apps.
2. In the Connected Apps related list, click Edit for the Workbench app.
3. In the Canvas Apps Settings section, in the Locations field, deselect Chatter Tab
4. Click Save.

Comment: Hi ,I checked my Salesforce org.But there is no app 'Workbench app' in Connected App.

Comment: Are you in a dev org? Does this happen in a prod org too?

Comment: This is happening in production org .

Comment: Does it take you to the workbench app?